# datagridview image column issue

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i have a datagridview connected to a sql database.Now,the dgview has a column that contans image(the 3rd column).Now the thing is, i am trying to stretch the images in the column.For this i've followed a youtube video and added this code on form load :

```
    Dim imm As New DataGridViewImageColumn
    imm = userdatagrid.Columns(3)
    imm.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch
```

now the problem is, in the video, the developer added columns manually from the dgview property which i didn't do cuz my sql db has it's own columns, for this reason using the above code gives me an exception "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.".What to do ??

Comment: If the image column is #3 {1,2,3} the index would be 2.  Arrays and collections start at index 0

Comment: so....what should be the new code?

Comment: i even tried replacing 3 with 2 in the code...but gives the same exception

Comment: i might add that i didn't import the /mdf db in the project as i am setting up an sqlconnection using code.....so i can't setup custom columns

Comment: The the DGV is set to autogenerate columns, you cant fiddle with them until you assign the datasource - there wont be any columns yet.  No idea of the context

Comment: u r right...there are no colums now...but as the form loads, the dgvw connects and retrieves rown/columns on form load...so is there no way for me do achieve my goal ?

Comment: Sure - just set the column property *after* you assign the datasource

Comment: but....as i mentioned, i didn't add any datasource(i mean didn't import any db in the project) as i'm setting up an sql connection by code....so..what then ? or do u mean....... i should add the lines of code after my data source code line ?

Comment: Yeah, thats what I meant by no context - there is always more than one way to do something and I have no idea what your code looks like.

Comment: thnq u so much, it worked